# ProASIC3 clock distribution issues

Tags: fpga, digital

I'm working with a ProASIC3L, and I keep getting these errors:
Planning global net placement...

Error: PLC004: No legal global assignment could be found. Some global nets have shared

instances, requiring them to be assigned to overlapping global regions.

Global Nets Whose Drivers Are Limited to Quadrants or Which Have No Valid Locations:

|--------------------------------------------|

|Global Net |Valid Driver Locations |

|--------------------------------------------|

|GLA |(None)

|--------------------------------------------|

|GLB |(None)

|--------------------------------------------|

|RST_N_c |(None)

|--------------------------------------------|

Info: Consider relaxing the constraints for these nets by removing region constraints,

unassigning fixed cells and I/Os, relaxing I/O bank assignments, or using input

buffers without hardwired pad connections.

Error: PLC003: No legal global assignment could be found because of complex region and/or IO

technology constraints.

Error: PLC005: Automatic global net placement failed.

INFO: See the GlobalNet Report from the Reports option of the Tools menu for information about

the global assignment.

The Layout command failed ( 00:00:01 )

The GLA and GLB signals come from a PLL block and are then passed down a few module layers to all the different components in the design. I'm kinda a rookie to clock management and tbh dont really know how to approach debugging. Anyone got any advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

I had to apply additional constraints for clock placement for PRO ASIC3, though this was very long time ago. My advice is to dig into specific ProASIC3L documentation and/or ask Microchip FAE. He/She has access to factory database that has similar problems and resolutions. I think this is a shortest  path to resolve this.